# Rails: Combining 2 active resource collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get all customers for a given shop from the Shopify API. Problem is that Shopify only lets you get 250 customers at a time.

Shopify returns the customers in an ActiveResource::Collection.

My solution is to make several calls to the API, storing the collection in a variable. But I'm having trouble figuring out how to merge the collections. I've tried:

@collection1 + @collection2

@collection1.merge(@collection2)

Is there a way to do this? My best solution right now would be to just return them in an array: [@collection1, @collection2] but it's a bit dirty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `to_a` method available for `ActiveResource::Collection` and then simply concatenate resulting arrays:

```
@collection1.to_a + @collection2.to_a
```